# Combobox Changed event in DatagridView

Tags: datagridview, combobox

I'm looking for the Event that allow you to know that Combobox in datagridview have been changed :(

Comment: Is it client side event or server side event you are looking for?

Comment: Better question is what framework is this question related to?

Comment: @hamza Did the solution work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for this under **Winform**

The `ComboBox` available in `DataGridView` is an editing control and you can hook up for the events for the same by subscribing for the `EditingControlShowing` event of the `DataGridView`

```
private void mygrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{            
            if (colName == "reqdcolname")
            {
                ComboBox cmbox = e.Control as ComboBox;
                if (cmbox != null)
                {
                    //subscribe for combobox events as you require
                    cmbox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cmbox_SelectedIndexChanged);
                    cmbox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cmbox_SelectedIndexChanged);
                  //since it would be call for each combobox cell subscribe in this fashion
                }
            }
}
```

If this is not the case then please update the question with more relevant details.
    }

Comment: Does this answer your question?